# Readimagefile(); function to get image

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I just figured out how to use bgi files in visual studio 2010 its working pretty well , i used the function write image file(); to save the image file of my output and it works fine but when i used the function read image file(); and open it nothing shows up its empty :"( . (HELP)
 when i use read image file() i comment the write image file function.

```
void main(){ 
  initwindow(500,500,"sample");
  writeimagefile();
  readimagefile();
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Are you using a windows port of bgi?  I gotta wonder why, but in any case both of those functions have parameters you're not passing.  You should read the documentation or post your full code showing your includes.

Comment: yes ,you are right but by default window screen pops up to save the file itself and same window pop up for readimagefile function but image is not leading up my screen just empty console screen

Answer (score 0):

Have you add the graphics library?

`#include "graphics.h"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
void main(){ 
initwindow(500,500,"sample");
writeimagefile("test.bmp", 0, 0, 500, 500);
readimagefile("test.bmp", 0, 0, 500, 500);
getch();
}
```

hope it helps